Nuxt-i18n incorrect prefixes on multiple domains
In my Nuxt3 application I'm using @nuxtjs/i18n package. The problem is that even though I am using the differentDomains: true option, I still get a prefix to all my url's for other than the default language. I've also tried the strategy: 'no-prefix' option, but it is causing bugs and the docs also mentions that it doesn't work together with differentDomains. These are my i18n settings in the nuxt config file:
    i18n: {
        customRoutes: 'config',
        pages: {
            'hotels/[hotel]/index': {
                da: '/hoteller/[hotel]/[[:preview]]',
                de: '/hotels/[hotel]/[[:preview]]',
                no: '/hoteller/[hotel]/[[:preview]]',
                se: '/hotell/[hotel]/[[:preview]]',
                en: '/hotels/[hotel]/[[:preview]]',
            },
            'hotels/calendar/[hotel]': {
                da: '/hoteller/kalender/[hotel]',
                de: '/hotels/kalender/[hotel]',
                no: '/hoteller/kalender/[hotel]',
                se: '/hotell/kalender/[hotel]',
                en: '/hotels/calendar/[hotel]',
            },
...
        },
        locales: [
            {
                code: 'de',
                file: 'de.js',
                domain: process.env.DOMAIN_DE,
                iso: 'de-DE'
            }, {
                code: 'da',
                file: 'da.js',
                domain: process.env.DOMAIN_DA,
                iso: 'da-DA'
            }, {
                code: 'se',
                file: 'se.js',
                domain: process.env.DOMAIN_SE,
                iso: 'se-SE'
            }, {
                code: 'en',
                file: 'en.js',
                domain: process.env.DOMAIN_EN,
                iso: 'en-US'
            }, {
                code: 'no',
                file: 'no.js',
                domain: process.env.DOMAIN_NO,
                iso: 'no-NO'
            }
        ],
        differentDomains: true,
        detectBrowserLanguage: false,//
        defaultLocale: 'da',
        langDir: 'lang',
        experimental: {
            jsTsFormatResource: true
        },
    },

I have console.logged out the available locals and I can see that the env variables has been correctly resolved, so it cannot be the problem. What else can cause the additional prefixes?
Nuxt version: 3.11.2
@nuxtjs/i18n version: 8.0.1
